# How to get all nested document objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new to mongo DB. I am developing an application using MEAN stack. On my back-end I have two models - Feature & Project.

Project schema has an attribute called 'features' which is an array of Feature objects.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    features:{
        type: [Schema.ObjectId],
        ref: 'Feature'  
    }
});

/**
 * Statics
 */
ProjectSchema.statics.load = function(id, cb) {
    this.findOne({
        _id: id
    })
    .populate('features')
    .exec(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

Please note that I have separate files for Feature and Project schema. I am registering both schema as mongoose models.
I also have a controller as well for projects which exports the following middle-ware function:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Project = mongoose.model('Project'),
    Testcase = mongoose.model('Feature'),
    _ = require('lodash');


/**
 * Find project by id
 */
exports.project = function(req, res, next, id) {
    Project.load(id, function(err, project) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!project) return next(new Error('Failed to load project ' + id));
        console.log(project.features.length);
        req.project = project;
        next();
    });
};
```

I would have expected all details of Feature objects in the project object above since I have used ".populate('features')" in the static load function of Project schema. But it is not happening, it returns an empty array for features attribute. Could anyone please tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Project schema has an attribute called 'features' which is an array of Feature objects.

Careful there. What you need is an array of ObjectIds that correspond to Feature documents.

I think you need to specify the project.features schema like this:

```
features: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Feature'}]
```

The populate function only works if both the code and the data are all 100% correct and it's very easy to make a mistake. Can you post the sample data of the Project document you are loading? We need to make sure `features` is really an array, really contains ObjectIds not strings or objects, etc.